# Poor sound using HDMI on cubieboard (cubian os)

Tags: audio, debian, hdmi, arm

I'm using a cubieboard with cubian desktop to play video through hdmi output.
(cubian is based on Debian 7.0 wheezy armhf, [more info here](http://cubian.org/2014/02/08/cubian-desktop-released/) )

the video is fine and I can hear the sound in headphones.
I could switch to HDMI sound output  (in vlc through : Audio > output > hdmi)

but then the sound become very noisy and I can bearly hear the video sound behind this loud noise :/

cat /proc/asound/cards  output  seems fine  :

```
0 [sunxicodec     ]: sunxi-CODEC - sunxi-CODEC
                  sunxi-CODEC  Audio Codec
1 [sunxisndhdmi   ]: sunxi-sndhdmi - sunxi-sndhdmi
                  sunxi-sndhdmi
```

when I launch alsamixer and switch to "sunxi-sndhdmi" a message says 
"This sound device does not have any controls."

and I'm stuck... I don't know what to try now

does any one experienced a similar issue ?

I don't know much about sound control on debian so any comment is wellcome :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and I solved creating a ~/.asoundrc in cubie and adding the next lines:

```
pcm.!default {
type hw
card 1 #change to 0 to use HP, 1 HDMI
}
ctl.!default {
  type hw
  card 1 #change to 0 to use HP, 1 HDMI
}
```

save and do a test

> speaker-test -twav -c2

This is not the best way to enable the HDMI/HP but it works

Comment: Wow, I don't realy understand what we did here but it worked !  nice answer thanks !

Comment: Cool thank you that worked. Afaik it is also possible to move the same content to `/etc/asound.conf` to have the settings active system wide.